# Grails AST Transformation "unable to find class" error

Tags: grails, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to implement AST Transformation in a grails project.

I get the following error when i run `grails clean` and `grails compile`. I dont know where i am going wrong, it is working fine in a sample groovy project.

```
Compilation error: startup failed:
/home/manoj/grailsgradle/ast/grails-app/controllers/ast/AstController.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class WithLogging ,  unable to find class for annotation
 @ line 12, column 5.
       @WithLogging
```

I have created two files namely `WithLogging` and `WithLoggingASTTransformation` in `/src/ast/` of the grails project directory.

WithLogging:

```
package ast

import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.GroovyASTTransformationClass

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy
import java.lang.annotation.Target

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target([ElementType.METHOD])
@GroovyASTTransformationClass(["WithLoggingASTTransformation"])
public @interface WithLogging {}
```

WithLoggingASTTransformation :

```
package ast
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ASTNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilePhase
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.GroovyASTTransformation

@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.CANONICALIZATION)
class WithLoggingASTTransformation implements ASTTransformation {

    @Override
    void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit) {

        println("******* inside ast *******")


    }
}
```

I have create a script in `/scripts` called `_Events.groovy`

```
eventCompileStart = {
    compileAST("/home/manoj/grailsgradle/ast", "/home/manoj/grailsgradle/ast/target/")
}

def compileAST(def srcBaseDir, def destDir) {
    ant.sequential {

        println "Precompiling AST Transformations ..."
        println "src ${srcBaseDir} ${destDir}"
        path id: "grails.compile.classpath", compileClasspath
        def classpathId = "grails.compile.classpath"
        mkdir dir: destDir

        groovyc(destdir: destDir,
                srcDir: "$srcBaseDir/src/ast",
                classpathref: classpathId,
                verbose: grailsSettings.verboseCompile,
                stacktrace: "yes",
                encoding: "UTF-8")



        echo "done precompiling AST Transformations"
    }
}
```

In `/controllers/ast`, i have created a controller `AstController`

```
package ast

class AstController {

    def index() {

        loggedMethod()

    }

    @WithLogging
    def loggedMethod() {
        println "i am doing some important stuff!"
    }
}
```

Comment: I downloaded the GGTS again, but it is still failing. Did you fix this?